# Do an action when woocomerce saves a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to save some options when a woocommerce product gets saved.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `save_post` action hook!

> [`save_post`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)

You could use this boilerplate to do your custom work when a product gets saved!

```php
add_action('save_post', 'do_some_custom_work');

function do_some_custom_work( $post_id )
{

    if ('product' == get_post_type($post_id)) {

        // Do what is necessary here!

        die('You hit the right hook!!!');
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- In addition to `$post_ID`, you could pass `$post` and `$update` to your callback function as well. Please read the documentation for more details!

```php
add_action('save_post', 'do_some_custom_work', 10, 3);

function do_some_custom_work( $post_id, $post,  $update )
{

    if ('product' == get_post_type($post_id)) {

        // Do what is necessary here!

        die('You hit the right hook!!! This is the product id: ' . $post->ID);
    }
}
```